# Unix command to find files read by specific user

Tags: files, users, monitoring, multiuser

I would like to find files accessed by specific user (even just read) within a folder tree. I thought the `find` command had this option, but it actually just searches for owner user. Is there any other command, or command combinations? The `stat` command offers access information, but doesn't display the user who made access.

Comment: This thread might be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205815/monitoring-file-and-directory-access-on-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is not stored by traditional filesystems. You have three main options:

- See who is accessing it in real time using lsof/fuser or similar;
- Set up auditing (take a look at [`auditd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd));
- Use something like [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: how does auditd compare with inotify, referenced above by wollud1969?

Comment: @atroon - Well, inotify can't notify you of which user did an action, so it seems irrelevant.

Comment: Huh, so 'filesytem events' does not include users.  Interesting.  I read the descriptions thinking it might be useful without getting into the details of precisely which events and just presumed there would be something on who had touched the file last.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only way to perform this is by activating auditd in your system.
this way, it will log the access to all files and you can grep the logs files.

Be careful as the logging will be "heavy".